# Grafana on docker: not able to find log

Tags: docker, grafana

I am using Grafana on docker. I can connect to the main UI. However I have some problems to establish a connection to a backend and that's why I would like to look at the logs.

According to the  [Docker file](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile), they should be located at /var/log/grafana/ . However this directory is empty. What am I missing ?

Thanks !

Comment: check the docker logs, docker logs <container_id>. might be an issue with docker container.

Comment: Are you mounting a volume to `/var/log/grafana`? Or are you `exec`ing into the container and looking there? Note that (as mentioned in the docs) volumes are not automatically created any more. Have you upgraded from a pre-5.1 version?

Comment: @RohanJMohite, thanks for your advice, it helped me to use docker logs to resolve my problem.

Comment: @SiHa, Thanks for your advice , howerer i can't mount the volume. Apparently, there is a problem between virtualBox and docker volumes

Comment: i am also exec into the container and the grafana log folder is empty.

Comment: Same here. latest 6.0 grafana docker image, either mounting /var/log/grafana folder or not has same effect, logs are produced *only* on console

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know this question has been dead for 15 months by now, but since it is the first result coming up when searching for grafana docker logs:

Grafana's logging mode in its default configuration is set to `console`. You can change that by setting the **environment variable** `GF_LOG_MODE` to `console file` if you want the logs to be written to both, the console and a file. Set it to `file` otherwise.
This works for `docker-compose.yml`, `docker run` or can be set at a later point of time from within the grafana-container by editing its `grafana.ini`

**Edit:** You might have to set the environment variable `GF_LOG_LEVEL` in addition to `GF_LOG_MODE` as your container might crash otherwise: `GF_LOG_LEVEL=info`

The different log-modes to chose from can be found [in Grafana's precise documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/installation/configuration/#log)

Comment: Just clarify that you don't need to use quotes around "console file". Here's a section of my docker-compose.yml:  

      - GF_LOG_MODE=console file  
      - GF_LOG_LEVEL=debug

Comment: Thanks, I edited that slip of mine. Most likely autoformatted by my smartphone.

Comment: "container might crash otherwise".... wasted hours literally due to this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Grafana docker image log defaults output to console.
So you can try `docker logs container_name` to find log